# Subset based on observation name

Tags: r, subset

I have a variable that contains different categories as observations. In total there are 42 (think red, blue, yellow and orange; under a color variable...).

I would like to subset the data such that there are 42 different data frames each based on those categories. So there'd be a red, blue, yellow and orange data frame.

My plan is to some manipulations on all the data frames using `lapply`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (x in unique(modshare$STCG.2.Commodity)) assign(paste0(x, 'modshare'), 
                                                    modshare[which(modshare$STCG.2.Commodity==x),,drop=FALSE])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that but without a piece of code nor a desired output is very hard read your mind and try to guess what is your purposes. Next time provide a reproducible example. Anyway, one way to do that is with `split(data, data$variable_color)` where `variable_color` is the name of the variable that contains the colors you want to split on.

Here is an example with the `mtcars` dataset in R.

```
splitted <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
```

that gives a list of data frames as you can see for example with:

```
 class(splitted[["4"]])
[1] "data.frame"
```